# Messages without any references

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm getting an error when the Monitor BizTalk Server job runs with the following message: "25 Messages without any references" I'm not seeing any tips on what to do about this, all I know is that I have 25 messages without references. Any idea what causes this or what to do?

Comment: What job is the *Monitor BizTalk Server job*?

Comment: The job comes out of the box with BizTalk to help identify issues and inconsistancies. It has 2 steps. Step one is to execute the stored proc [dbo].[btsmon_Inconsistent] (installed with BizTalk off the shelf). the second is to generate and error using [dbo].[btsmon_GenerateErrorString]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't found the cause, I have found the solution. It appears that there is a tool [BTS Terminator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkcpr/archive/2009/09/30/biztalk-terminator-download-install-info.aspx) that is used for catching just these types of issues. For a more complete listing on how to use it follow [This Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalkcpr/archive/2009/05/06/using-biztalk-terminator-to-resolve-issues-identified-by-biztalk-msgboxviewer.aspx). It really has a nice integration with MessageBoxViewer also